# Updating the customers database schema with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, database-schema, sql-server-2012, entity-framework-5

I'm using EF 5 in my WPF-Application.

Now as we've rolled out our first version (and the database that's used by the customer), we're of course developing and implementing features.

Some of them might require database-changes (new tables, changed datatypes, et cetera).

Is there some automated way to automatically update the customers database? Let's say when they run the application, check whether their DB-Schema differs from the one in the DBModel-Schema in code, and if not let it update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to read about Migrations. You can go here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712907 and there are a few links that talks about Migrations. Check them out.